# Mailchimp newsletter popup cookie expiration

Tags: cookies, mailchimp, newsletter

I have a MailChimp newsletter popup on my site, using the Subscriber pop-up option in mailchimp, i have created the piece of code and added it to my site.

The popup shows up perfectly, and the integration works flawlessly.

The issue i am facing is regarding the expiration time of the cookies.

When the popup form is closed, it remains closed for 1 year.
However if a subscription to the newsletter is made, the form remains closed for 3 months.

I have looked in the two cookies; MCPopupClosed and MCPopupSubscribed that are created by these actions to confirm these durations.

These values seem off to me, so i would like to change them.

I have searched around the mailchimp form generation area to see if i can somehow affect the duration of these cookies.

I would prefer if the "closed" cookie would last 3 months, and the "subscribed" cookie multiple years.

Comment: Have you found a way to set this through the Mailchimp admin interface yet?  Or through the embed code itself?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to set expiration date on page load.
I found these cookies are from Mailchimp on my site [_fbp, _abck, bm_sz, _mcid]

```
<script>
deleteAllCookies()
function deleteAllCookies() {
    document.cookie = "Name=_fbp; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
    document.cookie = "Name=_abck; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
    document.cookie = "Name=bm_sz; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
    document.cookie = "Name=_mcid; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
    }
}
</script>
```